# File name conflict in C codes generated by osmocom asn1c for GSM_MAP/TCAP protocols

Tags: c, gsm, asn.1

I have used the [osmocom asn1c compiler](https://github.com/osmocom/asn1c/tree/aper-prefix) (the aper-prefix branch), to obtain an implementation of the GSM_MAP and TCAP protocols. Each protocol has been successfully compiled. But during the use of both in one project, the following error is raised:

```
src/tcap/src/ErrorCode.c:35:20: error: ‘union ErrorCode_u’ has no member named ‘nationaler’
  { ATF_NOFLAGS, 0, offsetof(struct ErrorCode, choice.nationaler),
                    ^
src/tcap/src/ErrorCode.c:44:20: error: ‘union ErrorCode_u’ has no member named ‘privateer’
  { ATF_NOFLAGS, 0, offsetof(struct ErrorCode, choice.privateer),
```

I suggest that the problem is file names conflicts in C language, because there is same name structure with different definitions in the two different C files (e.g. `ErrorCode.h` which is used in both protocols)

```
/* ErrorCode structure which is defined in GSM_MAP protocol*/
#ifndef _ErrorCode_H_
#define _ErrorCode_H_
......
typedef struct ErrorCode {
    ErrorCode_PR present;
    union ErrorCode_u {
        long     localValue;
        OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_t  globalValue;
    } choice;

    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} ErrorCode_t;
.....
#endif  /* _ErrorCode_H_ */


/* ErrorCode structure which is defined in TCAP protocol*/
#ifndef _ErrorCode_H_
#define _ErrorCode_H_
.......
typedef struct ErrorCode {
    ErrorCode_PR present;
    union ErrorCode_u {
        long     nationaler;
        long     privateer;
    } choice;

    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
} ErrorCode_t;
......
#endif  /* _ErrorCode_H_ */
```

So try to solve the problem, using *osmocom PREFIX* feature:

```
ASN1C_PREFIX="TCAP_" asn1c -fcompound-names DialoguePDUs.asn tcap.asn UnidialoguePDUs.asn
```

However, the compiler reports the following syntax error:

```
FATAL: Cannot dereference dialogueRequest at line 13
FATAL: Cannot compile "TCAP_DialoguePDU" (21:1) at line 13
FATAL: Cannot compile "TCAP_DialoguePDU" (21:1) at line 13
```

Is anyone aware of this problem and a possible solution?

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you, as result of your comment, I edit my question and add the relevant code.